# How to collect billing information with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe to process payments. The problem is that I need the name, id number and address of every customer to satisfy European regulations. I see screen captures everywhere of invoices generated by Stripe that contain that information below "Bill to", but my invoices only place there the email even if I force to collect the billing address with

> 'billing_address_collection' => 'required'

How can I force it to collect the name and save the address for the invoice?

[image: Example invoice from Stripe documentation]
[image: My invoice]

Answer (score 0):

You should set the complete `address` on the Customer, and in particular confirm the `country` is set to a valid ISO 2-letter code. The country is critical to allow Stripe to format the address using the appropriate style.

Comment: But I want the customer to provide that information, not myself...

Comment: That's not how Invoices work. You control providing the customer information to say who the Invoice is for. You can look at the Customer Portal to see if allowing your Customers to enter billing address information there ahead of time suits your needs: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/integrating-customer-portal#billing-information-updates